# PropertyNotFoundException for p:column filterValue attribute

Tags: primefaces, el, jsf-2.2

we are trying to migrate our application from tomcat/websphere to was liberty profile.
Additionally we are upgrading the myfaces-version, we are using 2.1, to myfaces-2.2.

To save the current state of a table (filtering) we store the filtered value in a map and read it when loading the table (filterValue attribute of p:column).

When initially loading the table the correct method will be used (in our case its getFilterValue in the DataModel). But if we start filtering a column, the method wont be found anymore and the following exception occurs:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Die Eigenschaft 'getFilterValue' wurde nicht im Typ package.LazyModel gefunden.
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:245)
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:222)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:332)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.getType(BeanELResolver.java:83)
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getType(CompositeELResolver.java:99)
org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getType(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:150)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:199)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:257)
org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.setValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:153)
org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processUpdates(DataTable.java:746)
org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:787)
org.apache.myfaces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:213)
org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:822)
```

The table:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="group"
                value="#{bean.lazyModel}"
                selection="#{bean.selectedMulti}"
                rows="#{bean.lazyModel.rows}" paginator="true"
                currentPageReportTemplate="#{msg['data.table.pagereport']}"
                paginatorTemplate="#{msg['data.table.paginator']}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="#{msg['data.table.rows']}"
                resizableColumns="true" rowKey="#{group.pkId}" lazy="true"
                filterDelay="1000" emptyMessage="#{msg['data.table.empty']}"
                style="font-size: 8pt;"
                tableStyle="font-size: 8pt; table-layout:auto;"
                first="#{bean.lazyModel.first_m}"> >

                <p:column headerText="Name"
                    sortBy="#{group.name}" filterBy="#{group.name}"
                    filterValue="#{bean.lazyModel.getFilterValue('name')}"
                    filterStyleClass="column_filter" styleClass="wrap">
                    <h:outputText value="#{group.name}" />
                </p:column>

                ...
```

The lazymodel:

```
@Named
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class LazyModel extends AbstractLazyModel<Brand> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2247660292777600670L;

  /**
   * Konstruktor
   */
  public LazyModel() {
    super();
  }

 public Object getFilterValue(final String keyForColumn) {
    return this.filterManager.getFilterField(this.getKeyForPage(), keyForColumn);

  }
```

I think this should be the most important things to know.

So, i dont understand what changed between these versions that trigger the exception.

Every help would be great. TIA!

Comment: So when loading the page, the getFilterValue is called and it works, but when actually doing filtering it is not?

Comment: Yes, that's the strange behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this has worked before (it should not have (properly)), but the error you are currently getting is sort of expected. The `filterValue` attribute should be bound to a property with read and write access. You could bind each column filter value to an individual property, but it is more convenient to use a `Map<String,Object>` for your filter values.

Bean (lazy model in your case):

```
private Map<String,Object> filterValues = new HashMap<>();
// ... add getter and setter for filterValues
```

XHTML:

```
filterValue="#{bean.lazyModel.filterValues['name']}"
```

Comment: Maybe an upgraded PF version too? (I never used this attribute...)

Comment: So the difference is that i need a setter for the filterValue attribute? In older versions only that get-method was needed and the value was set at a different position in the code. I'll give it a try

Comment: @JensB: What older versions? You knowhere in you Q stated you started using a new PF version. Or did you not?

Comment: `filterValue` is for binding the value of the filter field. I would not make much sense to have an input field with a value which can only be read. As I started my answer, I was surprised it had ever worked for you (probably the value was lost when you did an Ajax update in that case). And please note that `.filterValues['name']` does not equal `.getFilterValue('name')`, you do not just need a "setter".

Comment: I changed our implementation to use a map like you suggested. And everything is fine now :)
I think it worked before because of a bug in the primefaces version. Unfortunately i don't find the link to the bug anymore right now...